# How can I check Is a packet HTTP or just TCP?

Tags: python, http, scapy

I am using scapy in python to capture packets. For some analysis I want to check is a packet HTTP or just TCP. How can I do that ? Is it related to /raw or something else?

Comment: TCP is a transport-layer protocol, and HTTP is an application-layer protocol that runs over TCP. It is incorrect to compare them.

Comment: Isn't it possible to know that, is a packet using HTTP (application layer protocol)  or not ?

Comment: @SergAnuke is correct. The HTTP packet is sent using TCP so it'll usually be broken into sequential TCP packets. You should write your protocol such that it only accepts the kind of communication you want, returning a malformed request error otherwise

Comment: Looking at their documentation, it looks like the `summary()` method is probably what you want. It'll give you some information on what type of communication you're dealing with

Comment: @Woody1193 Isn't scapy recombine broken TCP while capturing the packets? I mean, the packets I am seeing through scapy are broken ones?

Comment: @tarun14110 Is it? I didn't examine the API all that closely. I thought it enabled packet examination and creation

Comment: Usually http use tcp port 80, if that's the case you can use `pkt[TCP].dport == 80 or pkt[TCP].sport == 80`